# Outlook could't recognize recipients when button clicked

Tags: c#, outlook

I've wrote a program that should get Recipients email when button clicked. It works when I have used mailItem.Save() but this copy recipients and save it to draft folder which I don't want to happen.

Is there any way that I can call the functionality of "Check Names" ? or  What should I do to get all recipients instead of using mailItem.Save() ?

Process:

- Enter recipients email address to the "To field"
- Click the button to get recipients email.

Snippet:

```
//CC account manager when this button is clicked
private void uxCcManager_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    //check if user is authorized to use this feature
    if (!CheckAuthorization())
    {
        return; // Authentication failed do not proceed any further
    }
    //save mail items entered in fields else they will get overidden by space

    mailItem.Save();

    mailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();//check recepent name
    if (mailItem != null)
    {
        //check if EntryID (unique id passed as a parameter of the event) of the currentItem not null. 
        //the entry id changes when an item is moved from folder to folder(drafts->outbox->Sent Items).
        if (mailItem.EntryID != null)
        {
            if (mailItem.To == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please, enter the email address that you're sending email to!");
            }
            else if (mailItem.To != null)
            {
                //get individual emails from mailItem.To for the purpose of getting indivdual account manager
                if (!IndividualRecipent(mailItem.Recipients))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot identify one or more emails, please check names and try again.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A copy of my reply to your question at the MSDN forum at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7ba3272-1e1e-4601-a183-e63cd15ceea4/outlook-couldnt-recognize-recipients-in-compose-mailitemto-when-button-clicked?forum=outlookdev

Do not use the To property (as well as CC and BCC) - they are only updated by the store based on the recipient table when the message is saved. Worse than that, you are only checking for the To recipients, but it is perfectly legal to send to only CC orBCC recipients. And worse yet, To/CC/BCC properties generally only contain display names, but not the email addresses.

Use MailItem.Recipients collection, loop through it, and for each Recipient object, check the Address and Name properties.